# Erro em usar Between com codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Como criar uma função

```
SELECT 
    ii.sku,
    ii.cod_setor,
    ia.setor_ini,
    ia.setor_fim,
    sum(ii.quantidade) as quantidades,
    ia.desc_ambiente,
    ii.cod_coletor
FROM 
    item_inventarios ii
inner join inventario_ambientes ia on ii.id_inventario = ia.id_inventario
    and ii.cod_setor between setor_ini and setor_fim
WHERE 
    ii.id_inventario = '46' 
Group by ii.sku    
order by 1
```

**Tentei fazer da seguinte forma e deu erro**
[image]

**Mensagem de erro** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o certo do between no codeigniter é ser utilizado dentro do where, por isso vc estava enfrentando problemas

Comment: Perfeito, dessa forma funciona.
Porem, esse processo é muito lento .. será que estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: Verifica se os filtros estão corretos e claro ... os indices das tabelas

Comment: Filtros e indices estao ok e mesmo assim mdemora

**registos (11269 total, A consulta demorou 31,9350 segundos.)**



SQL:

`SELECT ii.cod_setor, ii.sku, sum(ii.quantidade) as quantidades, ia.desc_ambiente, ii.cod_coletor FROM item_inventarios ii inner join inventario_ambientes ia on ii.id_inventario = ia.id_inventario and ii.cod_setor between ia.setor_ini and ia.setor_fim WHERE ii.id_inventario = '117' Group by ii.cod_setor, ii.sku, ia.desc_ambiente, ii.cod_coletor order by 1`

Comment: executa um explain na query direto no banco que vc descobre pq esta lento

Comment: Recebi essa reposta:

`id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra
1
SIMPLE
ia
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
14528
Using temporary; Using filesort
1
SIMPLE
ii
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
246291
Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)`

Comment: Chefe, vamos la isso é caso para outra postagem, assim facilita, estamos misturando uma falta de conhecimento de Codeigniter com problema de sql mal formado ou lento

Comment: De acordo. Obg.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido com o código abaixo;

```
public function listar_arquivo_saida($id)
    {
        return $this->db->select("ii.sku,ii.cod_setor,ia.setor_ini,ia.setor_fim,sum(ii.quantidade) as quantidades,ia.desc_ambiente,ii.cod_coletor")
              ->join("inventario_ambientes ia", "ii.id_inventario = ia.id_inventario
    and ii.cod_setor between setor_ini and setor_fim")
              ->group_by("ii.sku")
              ->order_by("ii.sku")
              ->get_where("item_inventarios ii", array(
                "ii.id_inventario"=> $id
               ))->result_array();

    }
```